# Solving a Navier-Stokes equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I was reading a paper in solving a Navier-Stokes equation applied for 1D fluid flow in hydraulic fracturing. The below part I couldn't understand. Anyone please explain for me how do they get (4) from (2) and (3) and how to get (5) from (4)?

$$\frac{∂p}{∂x} = μ \left(\frac{∂^2 u_x}{∂y^2} + \frac{∂^2 u_x}{∂z^2}\right) ; \tag 1$$

$μ$: fluid viscosity

$u_x$: fluid velocity in x direction

$p$: fluid net pressure

The elliptic cross section shape corresponds to an ellipse with axes of width $2a$ and height $2b$ (image attached)

$z^2/a^2 +y^2/b^2 =1.  \tag 2$

The boundary of the ellipse is the locus of points $(x, y)$ such that:

$f(y,z)=1-(z^2/a^2 +y^2/b^2 )=0. \tag 3$

Note that:

$\nabla^2 f(y,z)=-2(a^2+b^2 )/(a^2 b^2 ). \tag 4$

By inspection (2) and (3) we can find out a solution to (1) with non-slip boundary conditions ($u=0$) on the ellipse boundary:

$$u_x (y,z)= \frac{∂p}{∂x}   (a^2 b^2)/2μ(a^2+b^2 )  (z^2/a^2 +y^2/b^2 -1); \tag  5$$

Then the average fluid velocity passing through the elliptic cross section of area $\pi ab$ is:

Thank you.

Comment: Can you cast this in $\LaTeX$ using MathJax?  it looks engaging but is very hard to parse as is.  Cheers!

Comment: I did your first equation.  Did I get it right?

Comment: Yes, It is very correct. Thanks

Comment: The hard way is to transform into elliptical coordinates.  The easy way is to take (4) as a fantastic guess for the solution, compute the Laplacian of $u_x$ and show that the Navier-Stokes equations (unidirectional flow) are satisfied with a constant pressure gradient. It’s pretty obvious the no-slip condition is satisfied at the wall. Finally integrate over the elliptical cross section and divide by the area to arrive at the average fluid velocity.

Comment: I also edited your equation numbers; you might check them!

Comment: Robert, many thanks for your help converting the equations in a readable form. May I ask if is it normal I couldn't see the pictures I attached?

Comment: RRL, could you please explain more in details? My background in mathematics is very poor to understand your answer.

Comment: Sure — you just need to compute $\nabla^2 u_z$ using (5) and show it satisfies equation (1).  Then show $u_z =0$ at the elliptical boundary. This is obvious because the term in parentheses is by definition 0 on the boundary.

Comment: Note that $\nabla^2 u_z = \frac{\partial^2 u_z}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u_z}{\partial y^2}$. For unidirectional flow, the pressure varies only in the $x$-direction and $\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}$ is a constant (no dependence on $y$ and $z$).

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most challenging part is computing the average velocity as follows.

The average velocity is obtained by integrating over the cross-section $E$,

$$\begin{align}\bar{u} &= \frac{1}{\pi ab}\int_E u_x(y,z) \, dA \\ &= \frac{1}{\pi ab}\int_{-b}^b \left(\int_{-a\sqrt{1 - y^2/b^2}}^{a\sqrt{1 - y^2/b^2}}    u_x(y,z) \, dz\right) \, dy \\ &=  \frac{4}{\pi ab}\int_{0}^b \left(\int_{0}^{a\sqrt{1 - y^2/b^2}}    u_x(y,z) \, dz\right) \, dy \\ &= \frac{1}{2\mu}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2+b^2}\frac{4}{\pi ab}\int_{0}^b \left(\int_{0}^{a\sqrt{1 - y^2/b^2}}   (z^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 -1 ) \, dz\right) \, dy \end{align}$$

Changing variables with $s = z/a$ and $t = y/b$ we have

$$\begin{align}\bar{u} &= \frac{2}{\pi \mu}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2+b^2}\int_{0}^1 \left(\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1 - t^2}}   (s^2 + t^2 -1 ) \, ds\right) \, dt \end{align}$$

Finally change variables again to polar coordinates to get

$$\begin{align}\bar{u} &= \frac{2}{\pi \mu}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\frac{a^2b^2}{a^2+b^2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \left(\int_{0}^{1}   (r^2 -1 ) \, r\,dr\right) \, d\theta \end{align}$$

You should be able to complete the exercise from here.  Note that the pressure gradient must be negative to cause fluid to flow in the positive $x$-direction, and, thus, $\bar{u}$ is positive.